# Alternative to rlocfind to find intersection of line of constant damping ratio with root locus in Matlab

Tags: matlab, controls, root

To find the gain at the point where the root locus intersects a line of constant damping ratio, the rlocfind function can be used, but the user has to manually select a point and Matlab finds the closest point on the root locus to the selection. Is there a way to find the exact point of intersection without having to make the selection manually?

```
h = tf([2 5 1],[1 2 3]);
rlocus(h)         
z = 0.707; sgrid(z,0)
k = rlocfind(h)
```

Can the value of gain be found without using rlocfind if the correct gain value is greater than 1? For example, for the following transfer function the gain value should be 23.4.

```
h = tf(1,poly([-2 -4 -6]))
 
minfun = @(k) (0.75 - tf2dampingratio(h, k))^2;
gain = fminbnd(minfun, 0, 1)  % 0.1970

rlocus(h)         % Root locus
ylim([-3 3])
z = 0.75; sgrid(z,0)
K = rlocfind(h)

function dampingratio = tf2dampingratio(h, k)
  [num, den] = tfdata(h); 
  poles = roots(den{:} + k * num{:});
  dampingratio = cos(pi - angle(poles(1))) 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a MATLAB function that can do that directly. We can, however, write a small function to do the calculation for us. We know that the root locus is the plot of how the poles of a system move when used in negative feedback with some gain (see the MATLAB [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.rlocus.html)). And the damping ratio is the cosine of the angle the pole makes with the negative real axis (illustration from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_locus)).

```
h = tf([2 5 1],[1 2 3]);
minfun = @(k) (0.707 - tf2dampingratio(h, k))^2;
gain = fminbnd(minfun, 0, 1); % 0.1970

function dampingratio = tf2dampingratio(h, k)
  [num, den] = tfdata(h);
  poles = roots(den{:} + k * num{:});
  dampingratio = cos(pi - angle(poles(1)));
end
```

[image: Root Locus Damping Ration (and Natural Frequency]

Comment: Note that this computation will only work for a second-order system. First-order systems don't have a damping ratio; higher-order systems have multiple corresponding to different natural frequencies.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I was wondering if there is a way to modify the mode to get the correct gain value if the correct gain is greater than 1? For example, I edited my question to include a transfer function for which the gain should be around 23.4 which I found using rlocfind but with the value found using the fminbnd function is around 1.

Comment: The thing to realize is that once the poles start riding the real axis, the damping ratio stays fixed at 1. So optimizers that search for the minimum won't behave nicely over that region. A more complete algorithm would first find the point at which the system is critically damped (when the poles first hit the real axis), and then use that gain as the upper bound.